# Makefile not respecting default value

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got a GNU Makefile with some default values set at the top.  One of them is

```
CC ?= gcc
```

Later, I have recipes like

```
file.o: file.c ...
    $(CC) -c $<
```

However, calling `make` with no other arguments produces output like

```
cc -c file.c
```

Why would the default value of "gcc" not be respected and why would this other value be inserted?  If it helps, I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because CC is a built-in variable of GNU Make set implicitly before reading the makefile (to cc), and `?=` only set a variable if not set (undefined).

Using `:=` you can set it despite of this, but I don't think that's what you want.

You could run make with option `--no-builtin-variables` to stop GNU Make from setting built-in variables. This will work like you want, but at the cost of needing that option every time you invoke make, and all other built-in variables need be defined explicitly by the makefile.